# im going to create two java threads(one thread to multiply numbers another thread to add numbers)

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads, thread-synchronization

I have to get the output like this:

[image: Expected output]

Here is my code. There are no errors. It starts with `PlusThread` and prints the first line. Then it will release the lock. After that `MultiplyThread` starts to run. It will print all the lines instead of notifying the `PlusThread`.

```java
public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object lock = new Object();
        PlusThread pT = new PlusThread(lock, 2, 10);
        pT.start();
        MultiplyThread mT = new MultiplyThread(lock, 2, 10);
        mT.start();
    }
}

class PlusThread extends Thread {

    Object lock;
    int start, range;

    public PlusThread(Object lock, int start, int range) {
        super();
        this.lock = lock;
        this.start = start;
        this.range = range;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = start; i <= range; ++i) {

                System.out.println(i + " + " + i + " = " + (i + i));
                try {
                    this.wait();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class MultiplyThread extends Thread {
    Object lock;
    int start, range;

    public MultiplyThread(Object lock, int start, int range) {

        this.lock = lock;
        this.start = start;
        this.range = range;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int j = start; j <= range; ++j) {
                System.out.println(j + " * " + j + " = " + (j * j));
                this.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

[image: Actual output]

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472572/execute-two-threads-which-wait-one-for-the-other-while-main-thread-continues it might help!

Comment: It's unfortunate that the Java gods chose the name `synchronized` for the construct that locks a lock because locks are _not_ meant for synchronizing or coordinating the activities of different threads. Locks are meant for one purpose only: To prevent threads from interfering with each other, by preventing them from accessing the same variables at the same time. For any other purpose, you should use higher-level synchronization objects; semaphores, barriers, blocking queues, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try this:

public class TestThread {
    static Object lock = new Object();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        PlusThread pT = new PlusThread(lock, 2, 10);
        pT.start();
        MultiplyThread mT = new MultiplyThread(lock, 2, 10);
        mT.start();
    }
}

class PlusThread extends Thread {

    Object lock;
    int start, range;

    public PlusThread(Object lock, int start, int range) {
        super();
        this.lock = lock;
        this.start = start;
        this.range = range;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            for (int i = start; i <= range; ++i) {

                System.out.println(i + " + " + i + " = " + (i + i));
                try {
                    lock.notify();
                    lock.wait();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    }

}

class MultiplyThread extends Thread {
    Object lock;
    int start, range;

    public MultiplyThread(Object lock, int start, int range) {

        this.lock = lock;
        this.start = start;
        this.range = range;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            for (int j = start; j <= range; ++j) {

                System.out.println(j + " * " + j + " = " + (j * j));
                lock.notify();
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir! it works..but it does not terminate console

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
static class PlusThread extends Thread {

    final Object lock;
    int start, range;

    public PlusThread(Object lock, int start, int range) {
        super();
        this.lock = lock;
        this.start = start;
        this.range = range;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            for (int i = start; i <= range; ++i) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(i + " + " + i + " = " + (i + i));
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

static class MultiplyThread extends Thread {
    final Object lock;
    int start, range;

    public MultiplyThread(Object lock, int start, int range) {

        this.lock = lock;
        this.start = start;
        this.range = range;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            for (int j = start; j <= range; ++j) {
                System.out.println(j + " * " + j + " = " + (j * j));
                lock.notify();
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```